# Removing boot partition from second drive

Tags: boot, partitioning

I did a clean Ubuntu install on a new disc and connected the old disc to use for extra storage. I deleted the boot partition on the old disc, but at start up the BIOS recognises the second boot partition anyway and the choose which disc to boot from screen displays. Can I stop the system from seeing the redundant boot partition?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

1. `umount` the disk.
2. Use `sudo fdisk -l` to see which partition **on the old disk** has the `boot` flag set.
3. Use `parted` to clear the `boot` flag.

Be very careful to operate on your old disk, not the disk you are booting from.

Read `man parted fdisk umount`.